# How to make Kendo ComboBox or Kendo Dropdownlist to appear as CheckBox?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, combobox, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo UI MVC ComboBox which works fine. However, I want to display the list of items in the ComboBox as a multiselect check boxes. Is there a way to achieve this functionality?

Here is my code snippet.

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
.Name("Country")
.DataValueField("Id")
.DataTextField("Name")
.BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Countries"])
)
```

I am passing the viewdata from the controller.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dropdown(combobox) templates are your friends. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/sfxN4/) makes use of MVVM with observable datasource as we have keep track of what is checked/unchecked and displaying the dropdown text preventDefaulting the default behavior.Rather, use multiselect as user488009 suggests to get rid of pain inventing wheels again.

Comment: I agree with using the MultiSelect option. However, my view page have more than one dropdownlist controls which are populated dynamically. So we want to avoid the number of clicks to select items using multiselect and rather use the checkboxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered using the KendoUI MultiSelect control?
http://demos.kendoui.com/web/multiselect/index.html

You might also consider a multi-select grid.  I would post a link to the demo, but I lack the reputation.  Look for the selection demo within the grid demos.

If you are set on checkboxes, check out this thread.  It has a custom template solution using the DropDownList control: http://www.kendoui.com/forums/permalink/5owXK3xeQUKGrE0MgS-Jog

Comment: Thank you for the links. I did see KendoUI MultiSelect control but our project requires the Checkboxes on the dropdown. I think I'll use the custom template solution using the DropDownList control.